# How to serialize proto3 message as an array

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

I use `protoc` to generate java classes used to serialize data. Sometimes, for example, I want my `json` to look like:

```
[
  {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": "a"
  },
  {
    "foo": 2,
    "bar": "b"
  },
  {
    "foo": 3,
    "bar": "c"
  }
]
```

I will define an protobuff message:

```
message Sample {
   uint64 foo = 1;
   string bar = 2;
}
```

And I have to define one more message, for array type key:

```
message SampleResponse {
   repeated Sample keys = 1;
}
```

Above `json` now looks like:

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "foo": 1,
      "bar": "a"
    },
    {
      "foo": 2,
      "bar": "b"
    },
    {
      "foo": 3,
      "bar": "c"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a possibility to get rid of that excess wrapper-message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the main purpose of the Protocol Buffer wasn't JSON serialization/deserialization the answer is "No".